# Cant access a specific memory address. on C program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory, gdb

I am working on the book "HACKING Art Of Exploitation " exercise Convert2.c page 61.

Here's my code. Below is my question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void usage(char *program_name) {
    printf("Usage: %s <message> <# of times to repeat>\n", program_name);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, count;

   // if(argc < 3) //if fewer than 3 arguments is used 
     //   usage(argv[0]); // display usage message and exit

    count = atoi(argv[2]); //convert the second arg into an  interger
    printf("Repeating %d times\n", count);

    for(i=0; i < count; i++) 
        printf("%3d - %s\n", i, argv[1]); // print the first arg 

}
```

GDB OUTPUT...

```
    ➜ git:(master) ✗  gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) run test
Starting program: /home/fruitdealer/clones/C_zombie/hacking/a.out test

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0,
    loc=0x7ffff7dd0560 <_nl_global_locale>) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:292
292     ../stdlib/strtol_l.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x555555554707: file convert.c, line 14.
(gdb) where
#0  __GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0,
    loc=0x7ffff7dd0560 <_nl_global_locale>) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:292
#1  0x00007ffff7a29122 in __strtol (nptr=<optimized out>, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10)
    at ../stdlib/strtol.c:106
#2  0x00007ffff7a24690 in atoi (nptr=<optimized out>) at atoi.c:27
#3  0x000055555555471f in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdeb8) at convert.c:14
(gdb) run test
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/fruitdealer/clones/C_zombie/hacking/a.out test

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdeb8) at convert.c:14
14          count = atoi(argv[2]); //convert the second arg into an  interger
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0,
    loc=0x7ffff7dd0560 <_nl_global_locale>) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:292
292     ../stdlib/strtol_l.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) x/3xw 0x7fffffffdeb8
0x7fffffffdeb8: 0xffffe220      0x00007fff      0xffffe250
(gdb) x/s 0xffffe220
0xffffe220:     <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffe220>
(gdb) x/s 0xffffe250
0xffffe250:     <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffe250>
(gdb) x/sw 0xffffe250
0xffffe250:     <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffe250>
(gdb)
```

I posted all of gdb output because i wasn't sure how much of it you would need. My problem lies at the bottom of my GDB output when i run "x/s" on gdb and get the `<error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffe250>` error.

On the book Jon Erickson is able to access `0xffffe220` and `0x00007fff` and then he has an error on `0xffffe250` this part of memory.

What am i missing?

Why can't i access any of the three addresses in `0x7fffffffdeb8`?

Answer (score 4):

The first half of the address is cut off. If you notice, it takes 8 bytes to store the addresses because you are on a 64 bit machine, not 32. You are trying to access a truncated address.

Rather than three addresses at `0x7fffffffdeb8`, you are looking at one and a half. Try accessing a byte that starts with `0x00007fff`...

Comment: In other words, don't use `x/3xw`, use `x/3gx` instead.

Comment: Ok i see. Thank you.  I will use `x/3gx` the "g" for giant.  Can you tell me how you are able to tell this is a 64-bit system just by looking at my gdb output? Blessings.

Comment: @Joelalexis you can tell by looking at the addresses the GDB outputs. On a 32-bit system, the memory address range is [0 to ((2^32)-1)] which is equal to [0x00000000 - 0xffffffff]. If you see an address that is outside this range in the GDB output (such as "loc=0x7ffff7dd0560"), that indicates you are on a 64-bit system. Alternatively you can examine the stack, as you are already doing.